# Adding another page other than index.html

Tags: html, express, nginx, forever

I started my own VPS, and started a web server using NGINX. I have an index.html. How do I create other pages, like an about page, and having it live at www.my-domain-name.com/about/

Does this mean I have to edit my app.js file, if so, how?

Amendment: I added Lazar's suggested amendment to the Express code to get the about.html.

```
'use strict';

const express = require("express");
const app = express();

// Static css/js files
app.use('/static', express.static('./dist'));

app.get("/", function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile( __dirname + '/index.html');
});

app.get("/about", function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile( __dirname + '/about.html');
});

const port = 3001;

// Start server
app.listen(port, function() {
  console.log("Listening on " + port);
});
```

In index.html, the link to the about page is:

```
<a href="/about.html">About me.</a>
```

Both `/about` and `/about.html` don't currently work and receive the error message: Cannot GET /about.html

Edit: I am using `forever`, so I had to `forever restartall`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering that you are using express, for every created route, create appropriate html page - or use some other thing, like handlebars, etc.

For example you created index.html for "/" route.
For about us route, create aboutus.html

```
app.get("/aboutus", function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile( __dirname + '/aboutus.html');
});
```

and so on...

For more info check their official web page: https://expressjs.com/

Comment: I added an about route in my app.js and the link to the page (<h2><a href="/about">About me.</a></h2>), but it still gives me the error: Cannot GET /about.html

Comment: I think that in order for us to help you you should put more of your code here. Show us index.html, but for now, try <h2><a href="./about.html">About me.</a></h2>

Comment: I confirmed with a friend, Lazar's solution works! What I forgot to do was to "forever restartall" [I am using "forever"]